# Using a cache with TLS

Tags: java, caching, tls1.2, squid

I am wondering if there is a solution to my problem. As a summary, I need a non-intrusive Web response cache for users that authenticate via a client certificate and are authorised to see URLs based on that.

I have a JEE application and I would like to cache responses to Web requests. I am trying to do it as transparent as possible (ie. without messing with the code), so I found Squid.

My problem is that users might authenticate themselves via a client certificate (or the absence of it) getting authorisation based on this, and this is what makes things "difficult". Is there a way to configure Squid, or any other software, to cache the results after the communication has been established by Tomcat? Something like a cache that is triggered by my application right after the TLS handshake is over and Shiro has been called (because user permissions depend on their certificate). The fact that users have to be authorised by my app make me think that the only way is to create Java code for this, not using Squid or similar software transparently.

I am sure this is a problem that has happened before.

Comment: If you have end-to-end TLS, then Squid only sees encrypted data, so it cannot cache it.

Comment: I know, as you can see in my question. I am looking for some sort of alternative, since I suppose this problem has happened before